# Offer a discount to a user paying with venmo

Tags: paypal, braintree, venmo

We want to enable customers to get discounts through our website. I'm curious whether we can support a discount flow when a customer pays with venmo, specifically.

The situation: a customer comes with a $10 discount to our marketplace website. The $10 discount is paid for by the site, and not the merchant. The customer finds a merchant that they like, and the two agree upon a sticker price of $100. The customer should therefore pay $90, and the merchant should earn $100.

Is it possible to ensure that the customer pays $90, and the merchant earns $100?

No details on the venmo / paypal integration page whether it would be possible to send the merchant $10 separately

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/pay-with-venmo/

Answer (score 0):

To send money to the merchant separately you would need to use a solution like Payouts or Hyperwallet.

Comment: Thanks @Preston PHX. A quick follow-up question on the merchant experience: As a merchant with a venmo account, would funds sent by the platform arrive directly in my venmo account, or would they go to a separate PayPal account?

Comment: Using the PayPal Pay with Venmo integration, the funds go to the PayPal account that is the `payee`